# how to build a visual representation of a wall and tiles with java script?

Tags: javascript, html

so I've been set a task for an interview an i'm struggling to finish it. 
The task is :
build a Html page where you can input the dimensions (height and width) of a set of tiles and input the dimensions (height and width) of a wall.

the page will return the number of tiles needed to fill the wall, then also give a visual representation of the wall with the tiles on it.

So far i've managed to do the easy math to work out the tiles but have no clue where to start to show the wall.

```
<form >

   Tile Dimensions<br />

   Width: <input type="text" id="tile_width" />cm
   height: <input type="text" id="tile_height" />cm 
   <br />
   Wall Dimensions<br />
   Width: <input type="text" id="wall_width" />cm
   height:<input type="text" id="wall_height" />cm

</form> 
   <button onclick="tileCalc()" >calculate</button>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function tileCalc()
{
 var tileWidth = document.getElementById("tile_width").value;
 var tileHeight = document.getElementById("tile_height").value;
 var wallWidth = document.getElementById("wall_width").value;
 var wallHeight = document.getElementById("wall_height").value;;
 var tileArea = tileWidth * tileHeight;
 var wallArea = wallWidth * wallHeight;
 var noOfTiles = (wallArea/tileArea);

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="you will need " + noOfTiles + " tiles";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm curious, but: an interview for what? Work, college..?

Comment: *cough* *cough*... `<table>`

Comment: As @MathewFoscarini implies, there's no shame in using a table for something it's perfectly designed to build. Nothing wrong with nesting for loops, either.

Comment: very short answer:
create a div#wall and put div's.tiles in it. Set wall Dimension on div#wall and for each div.tile the tile dimension. you can even color them differently. since its an interview you can position the tiles instead of float'ing. calculation rows with % operator.
have fun

Comment: I would have mixed feeling about this if I was hiring you.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing simpler than this. You can use a `for/while`-loop to iterate over the `noOfTiles` and create a div for each iteration-step:

```
var tileWidth = 100;
var tileHeight = 100;
var wallWidth = 1000;
var wallHeight = 1000;
var tileArea = tileWidth * tileHeight;
var wallArea = wallWidth * wallHeight;
var noOfTiles = (wallArea/tileArea);

for(var i = 0; i < noOfTiles; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = tileWidth + "px";
    div.style.height = tileHeight + "px";
    div.innerHTML = i;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/vxwSN/1/

Comment: @user2375922 Is your question answered? Then mark it as it is!